# Upgradable contract with corda

Tags: corda

I have some calculation code into corda APP. for example (stateA + StateB).
After some time after corda network was started I have to upgrade formula from

> (stateA + StateB)

to

> (stateA + StateB + 2)

Does corda have the best practice how to do it. For example upgradable contracts from Version 1 to Version 2 with a new formula. Any best practice how to achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: This computation is done in a smart contract or in a flow?

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade guide for CorDapps can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html.